# VBA Excel-application.counta() throw application and object-defined error

Tags: function, loops, excel, vba

I am a newbie of Excel-VBA. I've tried to replace the all the first columns with "I love you" until the first blank row. However, the do until loop throw "Run-time error 1004, application-defined or object-defined error. I appreciate any response:)

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim RowIndex As Integer

Set sheet = ActiveSheet
RowIndex = 0

Do Until Application.CountA(sheet.Rows(RowIndex)) = 0
    Cells(RowIndex, 1) = "I love u"
    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes because `Rowindex` is not zero based, if you changed it to `RowIndex = 1` then it should work.

`.Columns` is the same